# Having issues with urllib3 requests inside a docker container vs base ubuntu (where it's working)

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, proxy, docker-container

I'm having some problems with a python script I'm working with, it's a crawler running on some pages. Anyhow, the script itself works outside the docker container, I tried replicating the OS environment inside the docker container, with the dependencies and everything. The python run-time doesn't spew any error but it rejects my requests.

I tried pinging the addresses + ports manually, the requests are going through, I tried debugging the project itself, I tried running the container with `--privileged` (I know I shouldn't but I just want to get it working), I tried to see if it's a port issue, it doesn't seem to be.

```
2019-08-30 13:10:41,716:INFO:root:Using proxy '37.201.115.94:80' ...
2019-08-30 13:10:41,811:INFO:root:Using proxy '212.117.86.172:55455' ...
2019-08-30 13:10:41,864:INFO:root:Using proxy '37.201.115.94:80' ...
2019-08-30 13:10:42,094:INFO:root:Using proxy '37.201.115.94:80' ...
2019-08-30 13:10:43,002:INFO:root:Using proxy '37.120.21.137:50379' ...
2019-08-30 13:10:45,032:INFO:root:Using proxy '80.149.121.126:8080' ...
2019-08-30 13:10:45,072:INFO:root:Using proxy '212.117.86.172:55455' ...
2019-08-30 13:10:45,233:INFO:root:Using proxy '89.27.165.167:8080' ...
2019-08-30 13:10:45,617:INFO:root:Using proxy '89.27.165.167:8080' ...
2019-08-30 13:10:45,822:WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5b672f4080>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /session/175ce1981a369f6af0ac28924ea8a3e9/url
2019-08-30 13:10:45,824:WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5b672f4b00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /session/175ce1981a369f6af0ac28924ea8a3e9/url
2019-08-30 13:10:45,825:WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5b676a5f98>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /session/175ce1981a369f6af0ac28924ea8a3e9/url
2019-08-30 13:10:45,827:WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5b672b0a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /session/175ce1981a369f6af0ac28924ea8a3e9
2019-08-30 13:10:45,827:WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5b672b0b00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /session/175ce1981a369f6af0ac28924ea8a3e9
2019-08-30 13:10:45,828:WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5b672b0240>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /session/175ce1981a369f6af0ac28924ea8a3e9
```

Comment: Did you mange to solve this? Currently running into the same issue.

Comment: @Filip, unfortunately no, I mean I passed it but not by addressing it directly.